# how to convert English Spelling with Bangla

Tags: android, flutter

I need to convert the sentence to Bangla text for speaking.

Example:

```
   How are you? -> হাউ আর ইউ?
```

If anyone can do this with any programing language Please share this code.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to find a translation library/API, and this site isn't for recommendations about which you should use. You'll want to find one that does a good job translating between the languages you're using anyway, so you'll have to test a few

Answer (score 0):

i think u need to see this

(Text-To-Speech) Service

https://pub.dev/packages/text_to_speech

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need **transliteration** rather than *translation*. You can take a look at this package:

[transliteration](https://pub.dev/packages/transliteration)

They have support for several languages, including Bangla.